# Chef solo how to install postgresql 9.3 and minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, chef-solo, test-kitchen

I am trying to install postgresql 9.3 with chef solo from opcode recipes but I get the following error:

```
Chef::Exceptions::Package: No version specified, and no candidate version available for postgresql93-devel
```

here is my code in attributes/default.rb but it just installs 9.1 and can't locate package for 9.3-devel.

```
default['postgresql']['version'] = '9.3'
default['postgresql']['client']['packages'] = ["postgresql#{node['postgresql']['version'].split('.').join}-devel"]
default['postgresql']['server']['packages'] = ["postgresql#{node['postgresql']['version'].split('.').join}-server"]
default['postgresql']['contrib']['packages'] = ["postgresql#{node['postgresql']['version'].split('.').join}-contrib"]
default['postgresql']['dir'] = "/var/lib/pgsql/#{node['postgresql']['version']}/data"
default['postgresql']['server']['service_name'] = "postgresql-#{node['postgresql']['version']}"
```

If I use this code instead to install 9.2 it is successful but minitest complains that version 9.3 is not installed.

```
default['postgresql']['version'] = '9.2'
default['postgresql']['enable_pgdg_apt'] = true
default['postgresql']['dir'] = "/etc/postgresql/9.2/main"
default['postgresql']['config']['data_directory'] = "/var/lib/postgresql/9.2/main"
default['postgresql']['config']['hba_file'] = "/etc/postgresql/9.2/main/pg_hba.conf"
default['postgresql']['config']['ident_file'] = "/etc/postgresql/9.2/main/pg_ident.conf"
default['postgresql']['config']['external_pid_file'] = "/var/run/postgresql/9.2-main.pid"
default['postgresql']['config']['ssl_key_file']  = "/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key"
default['postgresql']['config']['ssl_cert_file'] = "/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem"
default['postgresql']['client']['packages']  = ["postgresql-client-9.2"]
default['postgresql']['server']['packages']  = ["postgresql-9.2"]
default['postgresql']['contrib']['packages'] = ["postgresql-contrib-9.2"]
```

I am now using this in attributes/default.rb

```
default['postgresql']['password']['postgres'] = 'xxx'
default['sportdata-server']['database']['dbname'] = 'myapp_production'
default['postgresql']['pgdg']['release_apt_codename'] = 'precise'
default['postgresql']['version'] = '9.3'
default['postgresql']['config']['ssl']  = false
default['postgresql']['config']['listen_addresses']  = '*'
```

Comment: Which platform are you running on? i.e. ubuntu, redhat, centos, debian? What happens when you try to install the package outside of chef?

e.g. sudo yum install postgresql93-devel (redhat, centos etc) or sudo apt-get install postgresql93-devel (debian, ubuntu etc)?

Comment: I agree with @punkle. It's not up to Chef, but linux environment. You most probably haven't included postgresql repo. Here's the link how you could install postgresql in CentOS (if you're using that distro) https://www.openproject.org/projects/openproject/wiki/Installation_on_Centos_65_x64_with_Apache_and_PostgreSQL_93

Comment: Ubuntu 12-04. I can't login with kitchen login as I have no password.

Comment: Unable to locate package postgresql93-devel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally abandoned the opscode postgresql cook book and went with this:

attributes/default.rb

```
default ['lsb']['codename'] = 'trusty'
default['postgresql']['version'] = '9.3'
```

In my postgresql-server recipe:

```
file "remove deprecated Pitti PPA apt repository" do
  action :delete
  path "/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pitti-postgresql-ppa"
end

bash "adding postgresql repo" do
  user "root"
  code <<-EOC
  echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ #{node['lsb']['codename']}-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
  wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
  EOC
  action :run
end

execute "run apt-get update" do
  command 'apt-get update'
  action :run
end

packages = %w(
  libpq-dev
  git-core 
  curl 
  zlib1g-dev
  libssl-dev 
  libreadline-dev 
  libyaml-dev 
  libsqlite3-dev 
  sqlite3 
  libxml2-dev 
  libxslt1-dev
  postgresql-contrib
)

packages.each { |name| package name }

package "postgresql-#{node['postgresql']['version']}"
```

Answer (score 6):

I just finished doing this with CentOS, but I've never tried on Ubuntu. I notice a couple things:

1. You didn't enable the pgdg repo for 9.3
2. You're specifying some invalid package names. I *think* the defaults in the cookbook should be sufficient.

Try this

```
default['postgresql']['version'] = '9.3'
default['postgresql']['enable_pgdg_apt'] = true
```

You might also need to ensure that your VM doesn't come with the default postgresql version already installed. I ran into that with CentOS.

Comment: Adding the 'enable_pgdg_apt' worked for me.  I also couldn't get it to stop looking for 9.1/main/, so I added this bash script that chef runs before installing postgres: 

sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/postgresql/9.3 |
sudo rm /var/lib/postgresql/9.1 2> /dev/null |
sudo ln -s /var/lib/postgresql/9.3 /var/lib/postgresql/9.1 2> /dev/null

Comment: I know you're not supposed to leave comments like this on Stackoverflow, but thanks. I've been running into this issue for ages now and this is finally the fix that seems to do it.

Comment: This fixed my issue with Vagrant, Chef, Postgresql.  I added `"enable_pgdg_apt" => "true"` to the Vagrantfile.

Answer (score 0):

This branch of the Opscode cookbook fixes the issue for me https://github.com/jackpine/postgresql/tree/feature/ubuntu1404. It is not yet merged with master: https://github.com/hw-cookbooks/postgresql/pull/150.

Comment: As of today it has been merged and available, v3.4.1.